# Finding shared values in two columns, and if A2=b2, put C2 in a new column

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013

I have an excel document where I have text values in two columns, and numbers in one, like this:

```
A    B   C   D
afd afd 123 
crq kul 876 
kul tem 942
```

I need a formula where if a value in A is matched somewhere in column B, then the contents of C will be placed in a new column D. I think I need to use a match or vlookup function. Can anyone help please?

Comment: To clarify, what I mean is that if both A and B have a value "afd" then the number 123 gets copied to column D.

Answer (score 1):

You want something like

```
=IF(ISERROR((VLOOKUP($A1,$B$1:$C$4,2,FALSE))),0,(VLOOKUP($A1,$B$1:$C$4,2)))
```

You will need definitely to edit the $B1:$C4 part to include your entire table. You may also want to make other changes for your use case.  Basically what this is doing is:

- Checking whether VLOOKUP finds a match for the value in A1 in column B
- If it DOES NOT find a match (indicated by ISERROR returning true) it writes 0 in the column
- If it DOES find a match it then writes the value in the second column of the table_array (in this case B1:C4) from the matching row into the column
- The dollar signs allow you to copy and paste down column D without messing up the location of the table.

DISCLAIMER:
I have not tested what happens if there are multiple matches so if that is possible this will take some tweaking.

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution is this:

```
=IF(SUMPRODUCT(--(A1=$B:$B))>0,C1,0)
```

You can put it into cell **D1** and drag down.